# Как получить данные из бд с помощью шаблонизатора Go?

Tags: html, mysql, golang, шаблоны

В моем html-файле имеются карточки с товарами, у них есть название,цена,описание и тд. Я хочу отобразить данные о товаре, которые хранятся в бд, в html-файл с помощью шаблона. С моей реализацией данные выводятся некорректно.

**html**

```
<section>
    {{range .products}}
    <div class="products">
        <div class="product-wrapper">
            <a href="" class="product">
                <img src="/static/pic/alice.jpg">
                <h1>{{.Name}}</h1>
                <h4>{{.Author}}</h4>
                <span class="old-price">₽ 999</span>
                <span class="new-price">₽ {{.Price}}</span>
                <p>{{.Description}}</p>
                <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="btn-default">В корзину</a>
                <a rel="nofollow" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-wrapper">
            <a href="" class="product">
                <img src="/static/pic/island.jpg">
                <h1>{{.Name}}</h1>
                <h4>{{.Author}}</h4>
                <span class="old-price">₽ 680</span>
                <span class="new-price">₽ {{.Price}}</span>
                <p>{{.Description}}</p>
                <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="btn-default">В корзину</a>
                <a rel="nofollow" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-wrapper">
            <a href="" class="product">
                <img src="/static/pic/ege.jpg">
                <h1>{{.Name}}</h1>
                <h4>{{.Author}}</h4>
                <span class="new-price">₽ {{.Price}}</span>
                <p>{{.Description}}</p>
                <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="btn-default">В корзину</a>
                <a rel="nofollow" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>
            {{end}}

</section>
```

**Структура товара**

```
type Product struct{
Id int64
Name string
Price float64
Quantity int64
Description string
Author string
```

}

Comment: "данные выводятся некорректно". И нам, естественно, надо угадать как именно они выводятся и как тебе нужно, чтобы они выводились?

Comment: у меня в бд ~20 записей, содержащие информацию о товарах. мне бы хотелось отобразить данные каждого товара в определенном для него <div>, как показано в html-коде, но в моей реализации сначала 20 раз отображается карточка товара с данными первого товара в бд, потом 20 раз карточка товара с данными второго товара из бд и тд.

Comment: А почему в цикле `range` `<div class="product-wrapper">` повторяется три раза?

Comment: он повторяется ровно столько раз, сколько у меня товаров в бд (каждый товар обернут в свой "product-wrapper") , просто не стал прикреплять кучу одинаковых строк кода

Comment: И ты спрашиваешь - почему 20 раз выводится один и тот же товар? Наверно потому что ты 20 раз его выводишь.

Comment: Следует оставить один единственный `<div class="product-wrapper">` и __понять__ что происходит с ним на итерации цикла `range`.

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы каждый раз выводился следующий товар из бд в каждом "product-wrapper"?

Comment: @КириллВоронков у вас уже написано `{{range .products}}` , оно будет итерировать массив ваших товаров в div-е. просто оставьте один див.

Comment: Всем спасибо, получилось